# Unity - File not writing on Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, save

I've been trying to get this to work for the last couple of hours and it's driving me nuts.

I have a method set up to save out data, which works flawlessly on PC, however, on Android it will not write the file. Here's my code:

```
 public void Save()
{
    string data = buildJson();

    File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerSave.json", data);
    Debug.Log("File Saved: " + Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerSave.json");
}
```

Not sure why it's not working. From what I can tell reading other threads, using the Application.persistantDataPath is the correct thing to do.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If WriteAllText failed, an exception would be thrown. Why not try catch the exception and check what the error is?

Comment: I have been trying this but I haven't found a way to read these logs, if there are any being outputted. I also put in a Debug.Log just to test, but I am also not seeing it being output. I've tried DDMS and logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

My problem was that the method wasn't even being called correctly.

I had created a singleton gameobject which was holding the script with my save method in it, but I wasn't using a reference to save it, which meant it only worked when I was calling the save method in the same scene the gameobject was created. (Which was the case when I was skipping my menu scene in the Unity editor, but not when I was testing it for real in the app)

Answer (score -1):

On android File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerSave.json", data) will write data on your **sd card** you need to add permission **android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** in your manifest file. The default manifest file created by unity do not add this permission.

Comment: Hey, thank you. How exactly do I do this? I have "Write Access" set to "External (SDCard)" in the build settings already.

Comment: Open Your android manifest file and after application tag is closed </Application> add following line   
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> befor </manifest> tag.

Comment: Assuming this is the file at "\Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest.xml" this line already exists in the file, and the problem still persists.

Comment: Are there multiple Androidmanifest files in your unity project?

Comment: In the same folder there is AndroidManifest.xml and AndroidManifest-main.xml, I added the permission to the -main file and the problem persists.

Comment: According to the Advanced Permission Manager app I have on my phone, it says my APK has external storage permission, so it must be something else unfortunately.